# spring cron jobs sceduler , monthly basis

Tags: spring, cron, cron-task, cronexpression

What would be the spring **cron-expression** if I want to run a job in the last business day of the month.
Like if the month ends in sat-sun I need to fire it on Friday.
Business day includes Mon-Fri.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `LW` expression see this: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

```
  The 'L' and 'W' characters can also be combined in the day-of-month field 
to yield 'LW', which translates to *"last weekday of the month"*.
```